# Add array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a table with phone numbers and Forms and trying to add them all to 1 data object eg.

name: name

 ph: [phone numbers]
Forms:[abForm]

but it is only giving me the last phone number and the last `abForm` of the table in the object.

```
// loop after 1st row    
for (r = 1; r < rowcount; r++) {
  cells = rows[r].cells;
  // first column phonenumbers    
  cellcount = 1;
  for (c = 0; c < cellcount; c++) {
    tel = cells[c].innerText;
    cellcount2 = 2;
  }
  // second column Forms
  for (c = 0; c < cellcount2; c++) {
    abForm = cells[c].innerText;
  }
}
let phone = [tel];
var data = {
  name: 'name',
  ph: [phone],
  Form: [abForm]
}
console.log(data)
// write out      
}
```

Comment: You surely have your variables defined before the loop, right?

Comment: You also reassign the values each loop so only the last one is in that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example is not working code, I will show you the key steps.

### Declare your variable first

Declare two variables of type array

```js
const tel = [],
  abForm = []
```

### add to the array

use the in built array function push to add new values to the array

```js
tel.push(cells[c].innerText);
```

### assign the result

since the variables' are already arrays, we can simply assign the whole array to one key of the data object.

```js
var data = {
  name: 'name',
  ph: phone,
  Form: abForm
}
```